# Which questions could do with a second, third or even fourth answer?

Tags: discussion

I've spent some time over the last few weeks adding additional answers to some questions; for the most part it is a thankless task, certainly isn't as much fun as being an early answer that immediately solves problem, but it is worthwhile.

Can we bring together a list of questions that would benefit from having an additional point of view? based upon our collective knowledge of the site we can probably come up with a list of half a dozen questions that could be improved by more than one answer.

Comment: I'd say both of my self answered questions at least. And nearly all I answered may profit for better worded answers

Comment: Would it be possible to create an additional tab, like the unanswered one so that users could easily see `questions that would benefit from having an additional point of view`?